# How to determine if a bitmap is bright or dark?

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap

I want to find out if a bitmap is rather bright or dark. I realize that "rather bright or dark" is not a very precise definition, but I just need to come up with something very simple.

My idea was to convert the bitmap to a monochrome bitmap and then just compare the amount of white pixels with the amount of black pixels.

Here is my C#-code:

```
private bool IsDark(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        if (bitmap == null)
            return true;

        var countWhite = 0;
        var countBlack = 0;

        // Convert bitmap to black and white (monchrome)
        var bwBitmap = bitmap.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);

        for (int x = 0; x < bwBitmap.Width - 1; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bwBitmap.Height - 1; y++)
            {
                var color = bwBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
                if (color.A == 255)
                    countWhite++;
                else
                    countBlack++;
            }
        }

        return countBlack > countWhite;
    }
```

What I don't understand: the amount of black pixels is always 0 - no matter what bitmap I am using.

What am I missing?

Also: I am pretty sure there is more efficient ways to solve this task. But at this point I just want to understand why the above code fails...

Thanks guys!
Ingmar

Comment: `color.A` represent the Alpha channel, it has nothing to do with black and white.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713103/detect-bright-and-dark-images?rq=1

Comment: Your main tuning point is now inside `bitmap.Clone()` and you have little control over it. You could also scan the bitmap and Add the R,G,B values for a 0..765 value per pixel. Then you can Average that or Count-with-treshold.

Comment: (at)Alessandro, that's it. Of course, while running my code, I checked other properties too (e.g. R, G, B, Name), but they always pointed to White. I have no idea why I ended up checking the Alpha channel. In any case this was a stupid idea. I am now checking for color.Name == "ffffffff" and now it works.

Comment: (at)Ratna and Henk: Thanks, but way tom complicated for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start for, you can try with something like this:

```
if (color.R == 0 && color.G == 0 && color.B == 0)
{
    // black
    countBlack++;
}
else if (color.R == 255 && color.G == 255 && color.B == 255)
{
    // white
    countWhite++;
}
else
{
    // neither black or white
}
```

As a side note `GetPixel(x, y)` is slow, take a look at [Bitmap.LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx).

Comment: (at)Alessandro: Yes, this works fine. Thanks! And thank you for you suggestion convening the Bitmap.LockBits. I was aware of this, but as I wrote in my original post, at this point I just wanted to understand what was wrong about my code.